# Iterate over limited dict_values in python3

Tags: python-3.x

Using py3, I am trying to simply iterate over `dict_values` which is a view in python3 and not `list`, so I can't do `dict_values[:limit]` anymore.

---

can't do below in py3,

```
In [1]: large_dict_values = large_dict.values()

In[2]:type(large_dict_values)
Out[2]: dict_values

In[3]:limit=5

In [4]: [print(item) for item in large_dict_values[:limit]]  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-eae6bfe09d50> in <module>
----> 1 [print(item) for item in large_dict_values[:limit]]

TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable
```

---

Of course one can convert this `view`(dict_values) to `list` as below, but consider if I have huge number of elements in view, converting to list is memory costly operation.
This is what I could reach up to,

```
In [10]: large_dict_values = large_dict.values()

In[11]:type(large_dict_values)
Out[11]: dict_values

In [13]: dict_values_list = list(large_dict_values)

In [15]: [print(item) for item in dict_values_list]
Out[15]: []
```

Does anyone already fumbled on this and have better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
import string
d = dict([(c, ord(c)) for c in string.ascii_lowercase])
values = d.values()
g = iter(values)
subset = [next(g) for i in range(5)] # take the first five values
print(subset)
```